# Why arent my lists recording onto my graph? (or at all)

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, sympy

So I'm making code that supposed to track how the distance of an object impacts the force it makes, yet for some reason, my list function will only record my last value input into the while loop. In addition, the graph won't even show that value. Im using Matplotlib and SymPy, nothing really extreme for packages. Can someone please help me with these two issues?

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=1

print('Give it a minute please')

List_p = list()
List_x = list()

while x<=750:
    theta = atan(400/x)
    Fd=10*500*cos(theta)/(x/cos(theta))
    p=Fd*sin(theta)
    List_p.append(p)
    List_x.append(x)
    x=x+1

plt.plot([x],[p])
plt.xlim(1,750)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Force of P')
plt.title('Distance V Force of P')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `List_p.append(p)` instead of `List_p = [p]`? You could also have to initialize empty lists before the while loop.

Comment: How do I fix the list append? When I replace it with list P as you suggested it says it has to exist first.

Comment: Right, you would have to define the list before the first loop iteration. You can put `List_p = list()` before the `while` line.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop?  You're not accumulating or preserving any values from previous iterations.

Comment: Still not working, faster now for some reason though by like a half a second

Comment: The point of the loop is to generate the values and store them in a list. For some reason my code is not doing this. That is the crux of my issue, along with it not plotting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the issue is you're not plotting `List_x` and `List_p` but rather just `x` and `p`. Pass the lists to the `plot` method instead:

```
List_p = []
List_x = []

for x in range(1,751):
    theta = atan(400/x)
    Fd=10*500*cos(theta)/(x/cos(theta))
    p=Fd*sin(theta)
    List_p.append(p)
    List_x.append(x)

plt.plot(List_x, List_p)    # <--- here
plt.xlim(1,750)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Force of P')
plt.title('Distance V Force of P')
plt.show()
```

[image]